# Screen appears completely white when using ModernGL and Pygame to render a texture

Tags: python, python-moderngl

I am trying to make a minimal Moderngl example of about <150 lines so I can better understand how it works. The issue here is that when I try to render this texture (it is an image of a mushroom), it instead draws a fully white screen. What am I doing wrong?

Below is all of the code for the project (<200 lines). You can easily copy it and run it, however you do need an image to load into the texture

main.py

```
import moderngl as mg
import pygame
import sys
import texture

class Context:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.window_size = size
        pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self.ctx = mg.create_context()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        m = pygame.image.load("images/Mushroom1.png").convert()
        self.tex = texture.Texture(self.ctx, m)

    def get_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.tex.destroy()
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    def render(self):
        self.ctx.clear(color=(1.0,0.0,0.0))
        self.tex.render()
        pygame.display.flip()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.get_events()
            self.render()
            self.clock.tick(60)

c = Context((800,600))
c.run()
```

texture.py

```
import moderngl as mg
import numpy as np
import pygame

class Texture:

    def __init__(self, ctx, img):
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.img = img
        self.vbo = self.create_vbo()
        self.texture = self.get_texture()
        self.shader = self.get_shader_program("default")
        self.vao = self.get_vao()

    def render(self):
        self.shader["Texture_0"] = 0
        self.texture.use(location=0)
        self.vao.render()

    def destroy(self):
        self.vbo.release()
        self.texture.release()
        self.shader.release()
        self.vao.release()

    def get_texture(self):
        texture = self.ctx.texture((self.img.get_width(), self.img.get_height()), 4, pygame.image.tostring(self.img, "RGBA"))
        return texture

    def get_vao(self):
        vao = self.ctx.vertex_array(self.shader, [(self.vbo, "2f 3f", "in_coords", "in_position")])
        return vao

    def create_vbo(self):
        vertices = [(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0), (1.0, -1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0, 0.0), (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)]
        tex_coords = [(0.2, 0.2), (0.8, 0.2), (0.8, 0.8), (0.2, 0.8)]
        indices = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3)]

        vertices = self.get_data(vertices, indices)
        tex_coords = self.get_data(tex_coords, indices)

        vertices = np.hstack([tex_coords, vertices])

        vbo = self.ctx.buffer(vertices)
        return vbo

    @staticmethod
    def get_data(vertices, indices):
        data = [vertices[ind] for t in indices for ind in t]
        return np.array(data, dtype="f4")

    def get_shader_program(self, shader_name):
        with open(f"shaders/{shader_name}.vert") as vert:
            v_shader = vert.read()

        with open(f"shaders/{shader_name}.frag") as frag:
            f_shader = frag.read()

        program = self.ctx.program(vertex_shader = v_shader, fragment_shader = f_shader)
        return program
```

vertex shader source:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec2 in_coords;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 in_position;

out vec2 uv_0;

void main() {
    vec2 uv_0 = in_coords;
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 1.0);
}
```

and the fragment shader source:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D Texture_0;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;

in vec2 uv_0;

void main() {
    vec3 color = vec3(texture(Texture_0, uv_0));
    fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your vertex shader, you are redeclaring `uv_0`
`vec2 uv_0 = in_coords;`
instead of assigning the value to the output value defined above.

Change `vec2 uv_0 = in_coords;` to `uv_0 = in_coords;`